# LoginActivity has leaked window that was originally added here

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

So below is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.stecs.async.HttpRequest;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    CheckBox rememberMe;
    Button login;
    EditText email, password;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    HttpRequest jsonParser = new HttpRequest();

    // php login script location:



    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.example.com/portal/webservice/get_user_data.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // setup input fields
        rememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        login.setOnClickListener(this);

        // load from SharedPreference
        loadSavedPreference();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreference() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreference.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value",
                false);
        String name = sharedPreference.getString("storedName", "");
        String pass = sharedPreference.getString("storedPassword", "");
        if (checkBoxValue) {
            rememberMe.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            rememberMe.setChecked(false);
        }

        email.setText(name);
        password.setText(pass);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", rememberMe.isChecked());
        if (rememberMe.isChecked()) {
            savePreferences("storedName", email.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedPassword", password.getText().toString());

            finish();
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        // Intent in = new Intent(Login.this, IncidentsActivity.class);
        // startActivity(in);
        }

    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Check for success tag
            int success = 1;
            String eMail = email.getText().toString();
            String passWord = password.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                jo.put("email", eMail);
                jo.put("password", passWord);

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                String json = jsonParser.postData(LOGIN_URL, jo);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                if(success == 1){
                    Log.d("Login Credentials - UserName!!!", eMail);
                    Log.d("Login Credentials - Password!!!", passWord);
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, IncidentsActivity.class);
//                  finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json;
                }else {
                    Log.d("Login Falure!", json.toString());
                    return json;
                }
//              success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
//              if (success == 1) {
//                  Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
//                  Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, IncidentsActivity.class);
//                  finish();
//                  startActivity(i);
//                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
//              } else {
//                  Log.d("Login Falure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
//                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
//              }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
//          pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I am logging in to the app; its crashing and giving me the error as given below that has been extracted from LOGCAT:-

```
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543): Process: com.karmick.stecs, PID: 11543
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at com.karmick.stecs.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:161)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at com.karmick.stecs.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-23 14:14:31.625: E/AndroidRuntime(11543):    ... 4 more
03-23 14:14:35.185: I/Process(11543): Sending signal. PID: 11543 SIG: 9
```

Please help me. I am new to this and seriously need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `doInBackground()` works on background thread, everything related with `UI` move out of there

Comment: would you mind pointing out the line 161? probably `jsonParser.postData(LOGIN_URL, jo);` is returning null

Comment: Is your problem getting solve now ?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: My problem has been solved... Thanks a lot...

Comment: If your problem solved mark any one as an answer...that will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this code from `doInBackground()`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, IncidentsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

add it in `onPostExecute()` like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    if (file_url != null) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, IncidentsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: I have replaced the code and added it in onPostExecute() but still I am getting error and the app is getting crashed.

Comment: have you dismissed your pDialog in onPostExecute() method?

Answer (score 0):

Very first thing if only AsyncTask is using

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
```

Then do not define it outside the AsyncTask its bad practice. And remove all UI related stuffs from doInBackground only UI thread have permission to modify the views.

Your start activity code should be on onPostExecute() method.

Main problem is ProgressDialog Object thats why window leak error is coming, becuase your doInBackground is crashing.